# Login.apsx presents in Default Documents although it's not in the web.config file

Tags: asp.net, default, html

Before setting up my website on IIS, like almost everybody I was using the built-in web server(Cassini). I have a page called Login.aspx which I had set as a startup page and obviously this was reflected in the web.config file. After setting it up on IIS I started getting "The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.". I guessed it was something to do with the Default Documents. When I tried to open the default documents option, this time I got the following error:

> Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key
>   attribute 'value' set to 'Login.aspx'

To resolve this issue, I opened up the web.config file and removed the following section:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <add value="Login.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
```

After this, when I opened the Default Documents feature of the website I saw Login.aspx along with the standard pages and by standard I mean Default.htm, Default.asp, index.htm etc.

Now I'm very curious, why does Login.aspx get displayed in the Default Documents list when it's absent in the web configuration file? Why does IIS choose particularly this page and put it in the first place when there're lots more in the website? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You do one thing create index.html and in meta tag refresh it to login.aspx immediately.